# Usb data cable communication in Android

Tags: android, usb

I want to communicate with my android application from my computer with the usb data cable. What listener should I implement?

I think a TCP connection will suit my needs but connecting with it over the adb driver seems akward.

How can I communicate from windows to android using a data cable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a nice post about this subject [here](http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/). You basically need adb in order to do the port forwarding between the Android device and the PC. As an example:

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300
```

Then you can use standard socket programming, both in the Android device and in the PC.

Comment: i tried that (my ap uses a port 21121) then i turn off wifi on the tablet and run my ap (pc and android that are supposed to talk together). they don't the moment i do Socket socket = new Socket(mServerIP, 21121); the socket fails IOException

Comment: i think this will not work for me because i have the server socket on the PC (it does the listen and accept) and client socket on android. i guess i need to do port forwarding on android? i tried a coupe of free port forwarders but none worked.

Answer (score 3):

Android supports a variety of USB peripherals and Android USB accessories (hardware that implements the Android accessory protocol) through two modes: USB accessory and USB host. In USB accessory mode, the external USB hardware act as the USB hosts.

for more info see: [USB Host and Accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) and example [click here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/USB/AdbTest/index.html)

Comment: Unfortunatley USB accessory and host modes are directly supported in Android 3.1 :( . Not manny people have android 3.1 or higher

Comment: You can use external library. please see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html#choosing

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an USB data transfer cable (also called USB data link cable) which 
support API or SDK, then use the following code:

```
void usb2usbComm() 
{
BYTE        buf[65530];
LPU2URET    pU2uRet;
BOOL        bRet;
int         ret;
CString     msgstr;

ret = u2u_open();
if (ret == -1){
    AfxMessageBox("Open U2U device Success.");
}else{
    msgstr.Format("Open U2U device fail，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//send data
bRet = u2u_SendData(buf, 65530, ret);
if(!bRet)
{
    msgstr.Format("Send data error，return：%d", ret);
    AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
    return;
}

//receive data
while (1){
    bRet = u2u_RecvData(recvData, dataLen, ret);
    if( !bRet )
    {
        msgstr.Format("Receive data error，return：%d", ret);
        AfxMessageBox(msgstr);
        u2u_close();
        return;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
u2u_close();


}
```

See:
[Reference1](http://www.cnblogs.com/LiuKaiFa/p/USB_data_link_cable_API.html), [Reference2](http://blog.csdn.net/zzkjliu/article/details/12838383)

Answer (score 0):

If data volume is low you might just copy files back and forth by using MTP protocol. Readily available on most devices and does not require enabling USB debugging or using USB accessory mode.