# Android development is in VM but need to deploy & debug in local device

Tags: android, azure, adb, remote-desktop, portforwarding

I am doing an Android app by connecting to a Virtual machine in Azure cloud by connecting to it via RDP(Remote Desktop Protocol). One week ago I was doing my development in local machine but my machine crashed so I started working in cloud. Back then, working with my local machine I had these privileges

1)Using of 'use Host GPU' option while creating an Android Virtual Device
2) Use of HAXM or intel virtualization technology/Hypr-v as I had access to my BIOS to set that up.

And I have a Google nexus 7 device and I used to work with it when ever emulators cannot do the job.(Like taking a picture for real)

Remote VM, I have no access to BIOS in Azure so I cannot make use of HAXM to speed up my emulator and of course I cannot use HOST GPU option while creating the AVD. It takes a long time to fire up the emulator and to deploy again and again. (My VM is a Azure D4 with 8 cores and 28 gigs of RAM)

I need to find out a way to forward my adb port to local machine so I can deploy apk into local device but yet developing from the cloud.

I went through following links but did not have anything working for 4 days now. I am stuck with my development totally until I get a new machine. Can someone please help on debugging locally

[Usb data cable comunication in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632332/usb-data-cable-comunication-in-android)

[adb forward remote port to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415797/adb-forward-remote-port-to-local-machine)

https://bitbucket.org/chabernac/adbportforward/wiki/Home

Especially if any of you have configured the third link (chabernac's 
adbportforward) please help me by stating how to do it.

Comment: I have not tested this but in the past this is how you would access local serial ports to a terminal session. 
1. In the Remote Desktop Connection window, click Options.


2. On the Local Resources tab, under Local devices, click Serial ports.


3. Click Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both vm and mobile device should be on the same net to work flawlessly

Just plug your device via usb on localmachine and in terminal type

1. `adb tcpip 5555 (or the port you want to use)`

unplug your phone, test if you connect to the device

2. `adb connect <device ip>`

then

3. `adb devices`

it should show the device you're connected to

Now type this to disconnect from the device

4. `adb disconnect`

go to `%HOMEPATH%\.android` and copy the rsa keys:

- adbkey
- 2adbkey.pub

Go on remote machine and paste those two files to the same path.

Repeat step 2 and 3 to check if the device is connected

**This works on devices 4.2+**

This is the article which helped me a lot
http://www.cleansoft.lv/debugging-android-applications-remotely/